# Is this an acceptable idiom for NSThread in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsthread, gnustep

I have a small agent-based modeling-framework that I'm writing as part of a project. The different agents all run in their own threads and a supervisor class controls their lifecycles. So the supervisor class can cancel these threads. I know that there is an `isCancelled` method on `NSThread`. Using that, is the following idiom acceptable:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BugThread.h"
#import "Bug.h"

@implementation BugThread

- (id) initWithBug: (Bug*) aBug {

    if((self = [super init])) {
        [bug autorelease];
        bug = [aBug retain];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) main {

    GSRegisterCurrentThread();

    while(![self isCancelled]) {
        //bug does its stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always retain an object **before** autoreleasing it nothing says an object can't have `autorelease` call `release` behind the scenes.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Sorry, that was a typo! It's supposed to be `[bug autorelease];`.

Comment: @Richard `autorelease` makes the object owned by the top autorelease pool, which won't be drained until after control leaves the current method. There is an issue here, though -- after `init` runs, the object in `bug` is not owned by this `BugThread`. Vivin, you shouldn't be sending `autorelease` to that object -- it isn't owned here.

Comment: Could you explain that last part better? What does it mean that `bug` is not owned by `BugThread`? Sorry, pretty much an Objective-C newbie here.

Comment: This is the basics of [Cocoa memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html): If you need an object to live, you take ownership by creating it via `alloc` or `copy`, or by retaining it. You must give up your ownership when you no longer need the object. When the object is passed in to a method, you do not own it. If you do not own an object, you must not send `release` to it (including via `autorelease`).

Comment: But `bug` is a member of the `BugThread` class so it shouldn't hurt to send autorelease to it, right? My earlier typo had me releasing `aBug`, which is the argument passed in. I can see how doing that would be wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see. At that point (during creation of the instance), `bug` is `nil`, so sending `autorelease` actually does nothing. It's true therefore that it doesn't hurt, but it's unecessary. I guess you're copying the setter pattern, which sort of makes sense. It's just that there's nothing in that variable yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say so, since this is explicitly stated in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-SW3):

> If your thread supports cancellation, it should call this method periodically and exit if it ever returns YES.

I'd recommend that you take a look at `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`, though. They're intended to allow exactly this kind of concurrency while managing the actual threads on your behalf. See ["Operation Queues"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1) in the Concurrency Programming Guide.

Comment: Does `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` make multithreading easier?

Comment: On another note, I'm doing this on GNUStep and not on OS X. It appears that NSOperation and NSOperationQueue may not be supported under GNUStep. I can't seem to find any documentation for it!

Comment: Ah, yes. I assumed you were using Cocoa. I'm afraid I don't know much about GNUStep, but yes, `NSOperation` does make multithreading _much_ easier.

Comment: Not familiar with GNUStep however, you may want to look into GCD as well.

Comment: @endy: That's a good point! [libdispatch](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-228.18/) is open source, though I'm not sure how it works on other OSes.